# Is Hierarchical Recursive Grouping is possible in Tablix in RS2008?

Tags: reporting-services, recursion, reporting, service

Is Recoursive column grouping possible for tablix in RS2008?
If yes, please provided related link

Answer (score 0):

If not then why not prepare the data using a recursive CTE?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx